# IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions - TabLayout in DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, drawerlayout, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to implement DrawerLayout and TabLayout in one activity, however I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Here's the code for *MainActivity.java*

```
// ...
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
// ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        FeedFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ThreadsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        /* ... */ {

    public static FragmentManager FM;

    public static LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static FrameLayout CONTENT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
             */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                ACTION_BAR.setTitle("Voog");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
             */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                ACTION_BAR.setTitle("Mina");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        CONTENT = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        try {
            View tabs = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tabs, null, false);

            // if the call do this function is removed app executes without crashing
            Tabs(tabs);

            CONTENT.addView(tabs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tabs error", "Tabs error", e);
        }
    }

    private static ViewPager VIEWPAGER;


    private void Tabs(View view) {
        VIEWPAGER = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        //set adapter to your ViewPager

        try {
            FM.executePendingTransactions();
            FM.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            VIEWPAGER.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(FM, 6));

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(VIEWPAGER);

            TabLayout.Tab FeedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
            FeedTab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_whatshot_white_24dp);
            TabLayout.Tab TodosTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
            TodosTab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_insert_drive_file_white_24dp);
            // ...

            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    VIEWPAGER.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tabs error", "Tabs error", e);
        }
    }
```

*activity_main.xml*:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ddd" >
        <!-- ... -->
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*layout_tabs.xml*

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/color_white_semitransparent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainprogress"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the Logcat output:

```
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1626)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1421)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:712)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:605)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1085)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:389)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1421)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:712)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:605)
11-01 06:49:05.038 E/AndroidRuntime(3367):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
// ...
```

And FragmentManager log:

```
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): Run: BackStackEntry{417faa10}
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): add: FeedFragment{417a7340 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): Allocated fragment index FeedFragment{417a7340 #0 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): add: TodosFragment{41813ac8 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): Allocated fragment index TodosFragment{41813ac8 #1 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): moveto CREATED: FeedFragment{417a7340 #0 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.758 V/FragmentManager(3367): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: FeedFragment{417a7340 #0 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.768 V/FragmentManager(3367): moveto STARTED: FeedFragment{417a7340 #0 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.768 V/FragmentManager(3367): moveto RESUMED: FeedFragment{417a7340 #0 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.768 V/FragmentManager(3367): moveto CREATED: TodosFragment{41813ac8 #1 id=0x7f0d00ab}
11-01 06:49:04.768 V/FragmentManager(3367): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: TodosFragment{41813ac8 #1 id=0x7f0d00ab}
```

So again, this portion of code causes the issue:

```
private void Tabs(View view) {
    VIEWPAGER = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    //set adapter to your ViewPager

    try {
        FM.executePendingTransactions();
        FM.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        // ERROR
        VIEWPAGER.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(FM, 6));.
        // ERROR

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(VIEWPAGER);
        // ...
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Tabs error", "Tabs error", e);
    }
}
```